# Wordpress - get categories only from current post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I want to display the categories on single.php **only from the current post**. I'm using this code, but it displays all categories in use... What should I do?

```
<nav class="post-navigation">
<?php $args = array(
     "hide_empty" => 1,
     "type"      => "post",      
     "orderby"   => "name",
     "order"     => "ASC" );
     $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo ' <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';}
?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping this in the standard wordpress loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Believe you want to be using `get_the_category()`.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
}
echo trim( $output, $separator );
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

Comment: I changed my code and now, I have got this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmrwrd 
This display only categories of active post :) BUT I would like to change order to make it like this "main category > sub category > post title" and disable some categories by id, how to do that?

EDIT: I see your code now, how to do that in your code?

Comment: Without doing some testing, I'm not sure. Try working on it for a bit and see if you can come up with something. If you run into another issue, you can always submit another question. In the meantime, if this answer has solved your original question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.