# Wordpress: showing post categories inside loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have a small problem with showing all post categories for each post inside my loop on custom archive page.

This is How I try to show them:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'section' );
foreach ((array) $categories as $category) {    
echo  '<span class="kat-label">'. $category->name . '</span>';
}
```

As you can see there is a custom taxanomy "section" and I have there also custom post type called "games".

The problem is output. Some posts display correct cattegory names, some of them display none, and others show the same category name for example 7 times!

I was trying to debug WP and I got something like that for results where 0 categories shows:

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on bool in /home/....
```

And for others

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/....../archive-games.php on line 238
```

The same code works perfect on single post whre categories are shown correctly.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: remove `(array)` in for loop

Comment: Nope. Same result.

Comment: post your `archive-games.php` file code

Comment: Here you are: https://pastecode.io/s/jwxzif5f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So there was a BUG in WPML (I have checked the WPML changelog) multilangual plugin. Updating WPML fixed the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit so that other who later stumble upon this answer would know what the bug was and which version they have to update to?

Comment: It was FIX in 4.5.8 version - see the changelog. I am not sure but I think there was a problem : "Fixed an issue that caused that same taxonomy terms to be assigned to the last queried object." but I am not 100% sure because my update contain 3 last updates. There coul be also come collision with WordPress core update because that problem showed after WP update.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution Is what you looking for.
Copid from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42563980/7207079)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
}
echo trim( $output, $separator );
}
```

**Edit:** - Improved

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if(!empty($categories)){
echo '<ul class='cats'>';
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>';
}
echo '</ul';
}
```

Comment: First one and second sollution shows zero categories, completly nothing :/ -> here is my custom archive-games.php page: https://pastecode.io/s/jwxzif5f

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing ID of the post or you are not mentioning correct taxonomy.
Try adding :

```
get_the_ID();


$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'section' );
```

Comment: Still nothing. Here is my entire archive-games.php page -> https://pastecode.io/s/jwxzif5f

Comment: get_the_ID()
this was the line we were missing. I have updated answer. This should work now.

Comment: I think that the problem is somewhere else. Meanwhile I was trying to turn off all plugins, and clear functions.php and I discovered that turning off "WPML Multilingual CMS" solved the problem. Now I trying to figure out why and fix that. Any ideas?